# Simple C++ project issue with XCode

Tags: c++, xcode

I am setting up a C++ project in XCode and it seems to not recognize my classes.  By default, there is a main.cpp file in the source folder.

I added a Node.cpp and Node.h file to this folder, and included the Node.h in my main.cpp file.  Unfortunately, it's not recognizing it, it says No such file or directory.

Why is it not linking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you include the Node.h in your main.cpp?

```
#include <Node.h>
```

will not work, you have to use

```
#include "Node.h"
```

Comment: Wowza... What a dumb mistake.  Thanks.  Why are these differentiated between, anyway?

Comment: Basically, the first notation is used for framework and system headers and the one in quotation marks for files in your project. Not really a dumb mistake though, in my mind :)